# Tensor out of scope in custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the total variation loss on a 5D tensor because I'm working with batches of sequences of images. So I tried writing my own custom loss function that averages the result of all the `tf.image.total_variation` in the 4D tensors.

```py
@tf.function
def avg_total_variation(x, batch_of_sequences_y):
    """
    tf.image.total_variation accepts either a 3D tensor for an image
    or a 4D tensor for a batch of images.
    But we have a 5D tensor for a batch of sequence of images.
    This custom total variation averages the total_variation for each sequence
    """
    variations = []
    for s in batch_of_sequences_y:
        variations.append(tf.reduce_sum(tf.image.total_variation(s)))
    print(variations)
    return tf.reduce_mean(variations)
```

Then I use it as such in the fit of the model

```py
model.fit(x, y, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, validation_split=0.10)
```

But I get the following error :

```
InaccessibleTensorError: <tf.Tensor 'while/Sum:0' shape=() dtype=float32> is out of scope 
and cannot be used here.
Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it.
```

I have tried to solve this error but unsuccessfully, how can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: Is you tensor a `tf.Variable`? Or you can add the tensor to the function arguments.